# The layout of the Windows Form Application is not displayed correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am developing the Windows Form Application.

However, I ran the program on another computer after building to see if it ran properly on another computer. But the layout of my program didn't show up the way I wanted it to.

[image: Layout I want (When I ran it on a developing computer)]

[image: Error Layout (When I ran it on a different computer)]

I saw an article saying that this problem could be caused by Form's AutoScaleMode Properties, so I set both AutoScaleMode properties to none,

(my application has two forms. One is the splash window that pops up at the start of the program, one is the main window)

but the problem has not been solved.

[image: Properties of main form]

My form has very ["tight" layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idd25.png)
I want my app to have multiple pages, so I used TabControl & TabPages and covered it with another tool components.

How can i fix it?

Comment: do you want the control's size/margins auto fit the screen? do you use some layout panel?

Comment: yes, there are many panels in this form

Comment: autoscale is a pain of winforms... try wpf instead?

Comment: As it happened, I felt the limitations of Windows Form and was looking for other GUI developments. Can framewalk like Electron implement functions like Windows Form?

Comment: i'm not familiar with that. but wpf is successor of winform and you'll benifit from it.

Comment: Thank you! Finally, is it smooth to change the Windows Form under development to WPF Application?

Comment: not sure -_- often not embed winform inside wpf, though possible.